# Passing dictionary with other values formatted between functions

Tags: python, file, list, file-io, dictionary

I want to pass the entire dictionaries's key, 2 more values which are being called in a loop hence will be combined and printed line by line. Values are being passed to another function but only 1st value of the entire dictionary is passed. I want all values get passed as shown below along with other variables. What would I do so that all values are passed not just one.

Here is my code:

```
class scoring:

   def values(self):
      dicts = {}
      inner_dict = {}
      with open("1.txt","r") as f:
         for line, score in zip(sys.stdin, f):
            d2  = ast.literal_eval(score)
            for key,v in d2.items():
               inner_dict = dicts.setdefault(key, {})
               inner_dict['s'] = v.get('s')
               sent = dicts[key]['s']
               binary = re.split("\s+", line.strip())[0]
               return key, sent, binary

   def score(self,key,sent,binary):
      <something>

if __name__ == "__main__":

   call = scoring()
   key,sent,binary = call.values()
   call.score(key,sent,binary)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have not done real coding in python, but I guess you are returning from the first iteration of the inner loop, probably that's why the other values never gets returned. You can save all your values list, and then can return list and access values from the list.

```
class scoring:

   def values(self):
      dicts = {}
      list = []
      inner_dict = {}
      with open("1.txt","r") as f:
         for line, score in zip(sys.stdin, f):
            d2  = ast.literal_eval(score)
            for key,v in d2.items():
               inner_dict = dicts.setdefault(key, {})
               inner_dict['s'] = v.get('s')
               sent = dicts[key]['s']
               binary = re.split("\s+", line.strip())[0]
               list.append((key, sent, binary))
      return key, sent, binary

   def score(self,key,sent,binary):
      <something>

if __name__ == "__main__":

   call = scoring()
   lst = call.values()
   for l in lst :
        call.score(l[0],l[1],l[2])
```

The basic idea is to do something like this:

```
lst = []
lst.append((1,2,3))
lst.append((4,5,6))
for l in lst :
   print l[0], l[1], l[2]
```

it will print

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
```

Comment: I get a error: TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__' on this line call.score(l[0],l[1],l[2])

Answer (score 0):

Your `return` statement is inside two `for` loops. This means that you are only going to go through the loops once before the `return` statement would leave the function. This is as much help that I can give without more information as you might want to use `yield` or to create lists or define class attributes that can be referenced by the entire class. Phase provide a more detailed desired output.